# Unity: Draw a trench onto a terrain

Tags: unity

I am making an RTS game and want to add the ability to dig a trench without redrawing the whole terrain as that is causing lag. The solution would need to allow a user to build a trench on the map and have a unit able to stand in the trench.
The game is using 3d models at the moment.

My first thought was to have the trench on a layer that is rendered on top of the layer with the terrain but that would give the problem that a trench would be seen even if it was behind a hill.

Is there an alternative or a solution?

Comment: Can you show us what your current (if laggy) method looks like, both in terms of implementation and visual result? This can help lead us toward solutions to achieve a similar visual result more efficiently.

Comment: Is this a 2D game using sprites or 3D with models? How are you drawing the trench now that is causing lag?

Comment: @DMGregory I have not tried to implement drawing the map with the trench appearing, just redrawing the terrain exactly the same when a new building is made to check the speed.

Comment: Sounds like you should tell us how you do that, then. It might give us some hints where the slowness is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the terrain into sections, then replace only the section where the trench is dug. This technique speeds up the game.